# React Native - Using objects from Custom Hooks

Tags: react-native, object, hook

I'm trying to get screen dimensions from a custom hook but I don't know how to use the results from the imported component.

Obviously I could use {MyDims.Width} and {MyDims.Height} to display the results but for my final script I need to use the 2 objects as strings, hence the useState().

Here is the imported component: getdimensions.js

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import {
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";

function App(props) {

  const [Width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [Height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  const getDims = () => {
    setWidth(Dimensions.get("screen").width)
    setHeight(Dimensions.get("screen").height)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getDims()
  }, []);
    
  return {Width, Height}
}
export default App;
```

And the main screen: App.js

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
} from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import useDimensions from './components/getdimensions';

export default function App() {
  
const  MyDims = useDimensions()

const [ShowMyDims, setShowMyDims] = useState({  
  width: MyDims.Width,
  height: MyDims.Height
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
      width: {ShowMyDims.width} and 
     height: {ShowMyDims.height}          
      </Text>  
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: **my final script I need to use the 2 objects as strings**. Do you need them as strings instead of object `{Width, Height}`?

Comment: @PrathapReddy Yes

Comment: Return it as `[Width, Height]` in hook and read is as `const [width, height] = useDimensions();` in your component. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working: https://snack.expo.io/@mobshed/usedimensions-test

Comment: Getting them as `0, 0` instead of actual value... Is that the issue?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: The question seems misleading to me. It would be better if you add the actual issue (getting `0, 0` instead of actual dimensions). Coming to the issue, are you able to `console.log` the actual values in `getDims` method?

Comment: const [Width, Height] = useDimensions(); console.log(Width); works well. I get the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return it as an array to avoid it being `object`. To get the updates from your custom hook to your component `useState`, add `useEffect` and trigger state updates upon change in `Width, Height` from your custom hook.

```
// In your hook component
...
return [Width, Height];

// In main component
...
const [Width, Height] = useDimensions();
const [ShowMyDims, setShowMyDims] = useState({ width: Width, height: Height });


// Add a useEffect hook to listen the updates
useEffect(() => {
  setShowMyDims({ width: Width, height: Height });
}, [Width, Height])
....
```

You have an option of **directly using `Width, Height` from your custom hook into your component** without having an intermediate `useState`.